# Can't connect with MySQL server from Android

Tags: java, android, mysql, jdbc

I am facing an issue when trying to connecting to a MySQL server from Android studio. I get this error *"Didn't find class "java.sql.SQLType"*

This is my code

```java
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class MySql extends AsyncTask<Void, Void ,Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void ... voids) {
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            String ssl = "verifyServerCertificate=false&useSSL=true&Unicode=true";
            String timeZONE = "JDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=Europe/Moscow";
            String url ="jdbc:mysql://10.0.2.2:3306/alphaProject?"+timeZONE+"&"+ssl;
            DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root","12345678");
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I get this error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: com.rashed.myapplication, PID: 10065
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$4.done(AsyncTask.java:415)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:305)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/sql/SQLType;
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.DatabaseMetaData.getInstance(DatabaseMetaData.java:768)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getMetaData(ConnectionImpl.java:1169)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:439)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:241)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:580)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:218)
        at com.rashed.myapplication.MySql.doInBackground(MySql.java:15)
        at com.rashed.myapplication.MySql.doInBackground(MySql.java:7)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:394)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:305) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920) 
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "java.sql.SQLType" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/com.rashed.myapplication/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes3.dex", zip file "/data/app/~~ZhlEMAszI-tUpZpBjVgYUw==/com.rashed.myapplication-eCNYPmPjKKX5fq_0a_DxzQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~ZhlEMAszI-tUpZpBjVgYUw==/com.rashed.myapplication-eCNYPmPjKKX5fq_0a_DxzQ==/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:218)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.DatabaseMetaData.getInstance(DatabaseMetaData.java:768) 
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getMetaData(ConnectionImpl.java:1169) 
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:439) 
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:241) 
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198) 
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:580) 
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:218) 
        at com.rashed.myapplication.MySql.doInBackground(MySql.java:15) 
        at com.rashed.myapplication.MySql.doInBackground(MySql.java:7) 
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:394) 
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:305) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
```

My server is running on `localhost:3306`, and I'm using 10.0.2.2 to connect with my PC localhost.

Comment: The MySQL Connector/J driver relies on Java classes that are not available on Android (specifically, `java.sql.SQLType`, introduced in Java 8). As a result, you cannot use this driver on Android. In general, you shouldn't use JDBC from Android anyway, but instead of use a REST API (e.g. using Spring Boot) to mediate between your Android app and the database. Alternatively, if you insist on using JDBC, you will need to downgrade to a 5.1 version of MySQL Connector/J.

Comment: so i should learn and use spring boot .. right this the correct way to connect mysql with android ?

Comment: You don't have to learn Spring Boot, but it is one of the more common platforms in Java. You can also use another REST framework, or even another language (e.g. PHP) to implement a REST API to mediate between your application and the database.